# How do I tell the compiler not to evaluate an argument?

Tags: rust

I'd like to instruct the Rust compiler to not evaluate an argument under any circumstance.  Here is an example:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

trait CheckTrait {
    fn check(b : bool);
}

struct CheckStructA {}

struct CheckStructB {}

impl CheckTrait for CheckStructA {
    fn check(_b : bool) {
        println!("CheckStructA");
    }
}

impl CheckTrait for CheckStructB {
    // compiler: do not evaluate the argument _b
    fn check(_b : bool) {
    }
}

fn show_stuff_a() -> bool {
    println!("Show stuff A");
    true
}

fn show_stuff_b() -> bool {
    println!("Show stuff B");
    true
}

fn test_a<T : CheckTrait>(_ : T) {
    T::check(show_stuff_a());
}

fn test_b<T : CheckTrait>(_ : T) {
    T::check(show_stuff_b());
}

fn main() {
    test_a(CheckStructA{});
    test_b(CheckStructB{});
 }
```

Here `CheckStructB` is effectively a disabled version of `CheckStructA`.  Where the comment is, I would like to be able to instruct the compiler not to evaluate whatever expression computes `_b` for `CheckStructB::check`, but still evaluate whatever expression would compute `_b` for `CheckStructA::check`.  The consequence on this code is that it would still output "Show Stuff A" to the console, but not output "Show Stuff B" to the console.

In C# this can be done by replacing the comment with [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DoNotEverTurnThisOn")] . I do not want to define the types inside a macro because that breaks intellisense.

How do I do it in Rust?

Comment: The C# thingy looks a bit like a configuration switch. In Rust [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) can be done with an attribute `#[cfg(feature = "feature_name")]`, which compiles the item it is attached to only if the feature is set.

Comment: @starblue I'll look into that, but it looks like Rust conditional compilation removes the definition entirely so that it can't even be called.

Comment: You can use a feature and its negation to have two different versions, the drawback is that it is a bit verbose.

Comment: @starblue The distinction is that C# leaves the definition, but deletes every instance of a call to the function, which has the side effect of not evaluating parameters.  If I write 2 different versions using cfg, then I'm just back where I started with having to figure out how to not evaluate the parameters of one of the versions.  If macros could be inherited by traits this would also be no problem since I could just define 2 different macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only evaluating arguments as necessary is called Lazy Evaluation.

In languages like Haskell, for which Lazy Evaluation is the default, an argument or variable of type `bool` is not actually represented as a `bool` immediately, instead it is represented as a "thunk" which contains the function to call and its own arguments (potentially thunks).

In Rust, since Eager Evaluation is the default, you need to explicitly represent laziness in the type of the argument or valuable. This is generally done by asking not for `T` but for [`FnOnce() -> T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) instead.

Therefore, you would rewrite `check` as:

```
fn check<F: FnOnce() -> bool>(condition: F);
```

Then, it's up to the implementation to either evaluate `F` or not, and if not evaluated nothing is executed.

*Note: if you do not want a generic `check`, you can take `Box<FnOnce() -> bool>` as an argument; it will however require a heap allocation... just like in Haskell.*

---

Let's see some code! [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d086e6a000bba5d42598224463a14c2a)

```
trait CheckTrait {
    fn check<F: FnOnce() -> bool>(b: F);
}

struct CheckStructA {}

struct CheckStructB {}

impl CheckTrait for CheckStructA {
    fn check<F: FnOnce() -> bool>(b: F) {
        b();
        println!("CheckStructA");
    }
}

impl CheckTrait for CheckStructB {
    fn check<F: FnOnce() -> bool>(_b: F) {
        println!("CheckStructB");
    }
}

fn show_stuff_a() -> bool {
    println!("Show stuff A");
    true
}

fn show_stuff_b() -> bool {
    println!("Show stuff B");
    true
}

fn test_a<T : CheckTrait>(_ : T) {
    T::check(|| show_stuff_a());
}

fn test_b<T : CheckTrait>(_ : T) {
    T::check(|| show_stuff_b());
}

fn main() {
    test_a(CheckStructA{});
    test_b(CheckStructB{});
}
```

Comment: While this would technically work, I'm going to be writing out the check call a tremendous number of times , writing out CheckStruct::check(|| -> { expression }); would be a nearly unbearable amount of extra boilerplate code than just writing CheckStruct::check(expression) like other languages allow.  I'm hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: @DanielV If boilerplate is the only problem, you can add a `check_eager` method that uses `check` internally, or wrap that construct into a macro.

Comment: @E_net4 I'm afraid I can't follow your suggestion.

Comment: @DanielV: This is the best solution I know of for your requirements, which says more about me than about the language or your requirements. If it doesn't suit you, do not accept the answer (click on the "tick" sign under the score) and wait for someone else to propose an alternative.

Comment: @MatthieuM.Your answer is useful as it is a possibility I hadn't considered, but it just won't work in my case.  It might work for someone else.

Comment: @DanielV: Sure, no worries ;) By the way, you do realize that the actual syntax of the call can be simplified to `CheckStruct::check(|| expression);`? That is, it's only 3 extraneous characters: `|| `. Annotating the return type `-> bool` and surrounding the expression by a block `{}` are both optional.

Comment: @MatthieuM. No I did not know that.  Also, in the example code check is defined 3 times (trait and twice in structs).  Could you be more precise how you would modify the trait and structs to implement your non memory allocating solution?  And where is FnOnce defined?

Comment: @DanielV: I've added a link to `FnOnce` (it's part of the Rust language) and rewrote your example entirely with the modified solution. I also added a link to the Rust playground, where you can compile and execute this code online to see that it prints the desired result.

Comment: @DanielV In your example, you could even simplify the calls to `T::check(show_stuff_a);` and `T::check(show_stuff_b);`

Comment: I think this will work.  Let me apply it to my larger project and make sure (I'm still new at this) then I think I can accept this answer.

Comment: @DanielV: Take your time to accept any answer; I personally prefer to wait 24h/48h before accepting as it can discourage competing answers which may have better solutions.